# Is the product of two full column rank matrices full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

If $A$ is a $T\times r$ matrix of full column rank, and B is another $T\times r$ matrix of full column rank. Then is the product ($r\times r$) matrix $A'B$ full rank? (If $T\rightarrow\infty$, I guess the question can be rephrased with regard to $A'B/T$.)

Comment: Is $A’$ the transpose?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=0$.